# the type of namespace of rows could not be found

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, datagridview

I get the error as below:

> the type of namespace of rows could not be found

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data;


namespace DataGridView1
{
    public partial class Cust_Form : Form
    {
        public Cust_Form()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void DataGridView1_Load(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {

            dataGridView.Rows.Add("1", "Mei", "US");
            dataGridView.Rows.Add("2", "Wei", "US");
        }

        //private void Cust_Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        //{

        //}
    }
}
```

What is the namespace that should I add to get rid of this error? I get my error at the "Rows"

Cust_Form.Designer.cs

```
namespace DataGridView1
{
    partial class Cust_Form
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // Cust_Form
            // 
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 261);
            this.Name = "Cust_Form";
            this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Cust_Form_Load);
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView dataGridView;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn Column1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn Column2;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn Column3;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewButtonColumn Column5;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewButtonColumn Column4;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your name space DataGridView1 is creating the ambiguity here. Is your control's ID "dataGridView1" with a lower case "d"?

Comment: yes, it should be "dataGridView.Rows.Add("1", "Mei", "Penang", "Edit", "Delete");", but I could not add it when I debug

Comment: In your posted code (method "dataGridView1_CellContentClick"), you have "DataGridView1" with "D" in upper case which corresponds to the namespace.

Comment: I have change the code as above, but it still cannot add into the row, what's wrong with that? I am 1st time using this

Comment: What is the ID of your DataGridView? Can you post the code of your form's designer.cs code?

Comment: Your event handler wiring seems wrong. You are wiring to "dataGridView1_CellContentClick", but the method in the from still has "DataGridView1_CellContentClick" with an upper case "D". Apart from this I don't think there is any other issue. After changing this, let me know if you are getting any compile time or runtime errors.

Comment: I have changed d code, but still could not add in the row.

Comment: hi sarathy, I can add in the row only when I click the button for column4/5. I wonder how to load it directly without clicking any button at the "DataGridView1_CellContentClick"

Comment: You can do it on Form_Load event from a data source. You can go through this link to find how to user the DataGridView control. http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=132

Comment: yes, I want to do a form load event from data source, but I having problem to load the data, I cnt automatically load the data without click a button. I have go through this but still cannot load it without clicking a button. Do u have any idea? What's wrong with my code? I have changed it to "load event" but still return me the same thing

Comment: I am hoping this article should help. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/5s3ce6k8(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access `DataGridView1.Rows`, but inside your namespace `DataGridView1` there doesn't seem to be a declaration of the `Rows` class.
Make sure such an implementation exists.

Remember, just adding a namespace isn't always going to fix your errors.

Comment: @user4562396 If you HAVE created Rows, make sure it's inside the namespace and be sure to include it in your example code.